# How to simplify my js code without loading the js file twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I hava many jsp page using the common function in body's `onload and onunload event` when using ocx control.So I extract the common function in one js file call `common.js` and import the js file in the jsp page.But I find the sometimes the jsp page could not execute the function in js file.Finally,I solve the problem in two way but I think there must have the other simple way?How to simplify my js code?

1. write all the js function in each jsp,it works well
2. in the each jsp file,includ the common.js,and in the jsp file the script call the function before load the common.js,but I think it have already be loaded two times

   ```
   //init(),asynclogin_onclick(),logout_onclick() function is in the common.js file     
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common.js"></script> 
   </head>
   <body onload="init()" onunload="logout_onclick()"> 
   $(function(){
   $.getScript("/js/common.js")
   .done(function(script,textStatus ) {
    asynclogin_onclick();  
   }); 
   });
   ```

   I  try to write the code like this,but it could not work.

   ```
   $(function(){ 
    asynclogin_onclick();   
   });
   ```

Comment: If you have a script tag at the top of the page, like above, then anything after it can access anything in that script that has global (window) scope.  What errors do you get in the console when it doesn't work?

Comment: Incidentally, the code in the question will never work because you're missing the 2nd set of script tags.

Comment: I have write 2nd set of script tags in my jsp page.Do you sure that  $(function(){ asynclogin_onclick();  }   can access anything in that script that has global (window) scope? The  asynclogin_onclick() is write in the common.js.

Comment: Yes, it definitely can, and since the script tags are synchronous the script is definitely loaded (or there's an error loading it).  Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Also, is it a typo that the 2 script Urls are different in the question?

Comment: Yes,Thank you . It is a typo that the 2 script Urls are different.It is the same.